# knob.js in wordpress not working circle counter

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add circle counters in wordpress using knob.js

Here is an example

```
jQuery('.knob').each(function () {

   var $this = $(this);
   var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
   // alert(myVal);
   $this.knob({

   });

   $({
       value: 0
   }).animate({

       value: myVal
   }, {
       duration: 2000,
       easing: 'swing',
       step: function () {
           $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

       }
   })

});
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/eea52/

Here is the knob.js file 
https://raw.github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/js/jquery.knob.js

I can't get this to work in wordpress at all. Has anyone used knob.js in wordpress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working... I forgot to add jQuery and had to edit the knob.js as well ended up using this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.knob').each(function() {

           var $this = $(this);
           var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
           // alert(myVal);
           $this.knob({

           });




           $({
               value: 0
           }).animate({

               value: myVal
           }, {
               duration: 2000,
               easing: 'swing',
               step: function () {
                   $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

               }
           })

       });
});
```